# Run knexfile.js from a db/ folder

Tags: node.js, knex.js

I have installed the nodejs package  globally.

After initializing via `knex init` and putting the file into a `/db` folder, commands such as `knex migrate:latest` won`t work anymore, because knex cannot find the file. Furthermore, knex creates the migrate and seed folder in my root directory

Any suggestions how to config knex that it always looks into the `/db` folder? Is there any way to do this via a `node-script`?

Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can give your config file location on `script`

add this on package.json

```
"migrate": "yarn knex migrate:latest --knexfile src/config/knexfile.js",
```

My knexfile is in src/config.

Comment: Is it possible to configure "migrate:make": "..." in the file? If so, where would I pass migration_name?

Comment: Yes, @MithunJack. It's a simple addition of script in your `package.json` file.

`"migrate:make": "yarn knex migrate:latest --knexfile src/config/knexfile.js"` should be enough

Answer (score 1):

Write your own client implementation which just uses migration API provided by knex.